# How to separate an array based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have two array like this.

```
var array1 = ["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5", "str6"];
```

How can i split the array1 based on elements in array2 so that the result become like this and store in 3 array(not always 3,depends on array2's items)?

```
var array2 = ["str2","str5"];
// Case1 result 
// newArr1=["str1"]
// newArr2=["str2","str3","str4"]
// newArr3=["str5","str6"]

var array2 = ["str2","str3"];
//Case2 result
// newArr1=["str1"]
// newArr2=["str2"]
// newArr3=["str3","str4""str5","str6"]
```

I tried this and i have no idea how to achieve result like above.

```
for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
   newArr = array1.splice(0, array1.indexOf(array2[i]));
}
```

`array2` acts as a breaking point. So if `array2` contain all elements of `array1`. It should generate 6 new array with only one item in each.

Comment: Please help me in understanding the logic that will decide how many elements will go in each array

Comment: Is it acceptable to have the arrays back as arrays of arrays `[["str1"],["str2","str3","str4"],["str5","str6"]]`?

Comment: here `["str2","str5"]` `str2` and `str5` are the breaking points in `array1 `

Comment: It's a good idea making your desired outcome perfectly clear. Otherwise, people will have to spend a lot of energy just to understand what you want (if they can), and most answerers (like me) will just move to the next question... on top of that, desired outcomes that are not exactly clear will generate a lot of wrong answers and downvotes, wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado +1, Like me, I am still trying to understand what really he/she want

Comment: array2 act as a breaking point..so if array2 contain all elements of array1..it should generate 6 new array with only one item in each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to start and achieve as you want

```js
var array1 = ["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5", "str6"];
var newArray = [];
var array2 = ["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5", "str6"];
var prev = 0;
for(let i in array2){
  var index = array1.indexOf(array2[i]);
  if(index != prev){
    newArray.push(array1.slice(prev,index));
    prev = index;
  }
}
newArray.push(array1.slice(prev));
console.log(newArray);
```

```js
var array1 = ["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5", "str6"];
var newArray = [];
var array2 = ["str2", "str5"];
var prev = 0;
for(let i in array2){
  var index = array1.indexOf(array2[i]);
  if(index != prev){
    newArray.push(array1.slice(prev,index));
    prev = index;
  }
}
newArray.push(array1.slice(prev));
console.log(newArray);
```

Also with dynamic variable

```js
var array1 = ["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5", "str6"];
var count = 1;
var array2 = ["str2", "str5"];
var prev = 0;
for(let i in array2){
  var index = array1.indexOf(array2[i]);
  if(index != prev){
    window['newArray'+ count++] = array1.slice(prev,index);
    prev = index;
  }
}
window['newArray'+ count++] = array1.slice(prev);
console.log('newArray1 : ',newArray1);
console.log('newArray2 : ',newArray2);
console.log('newArray3 : ',newArray3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single loop and look for the separation element and build a new array with the chunks. Later add the rest to the result.

This version works for recurring items in the array for splitting.

```js
function group(array, starts) {
    var index = 0,
        result = [];

    starts.forEach(function (v) {
        result.push(array.slice(index, index = array.indexOf(v, index)));
    });
    result.push(array.slice(index));
    return result;
}

console.log(group(["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5", "str6"], ["str2", "str5"]));
console.log(group(["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5", "str6"], ["str2", "str3"]));
console.log(group(["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5", "str6"], []));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 - Create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from the items of `array2`. Iterate `array1` using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). If there is no sub array, or the current string is found in array2 Set (using [Set#has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has)), add a new sub array. Always push the current string to the last sub array.

```js
const groupByArray = (array1, array2) => {
  const array2Set = new Set(array2);
  
  return array1.reduce((r, s) => {
    if(!r[r.length - 1] || array2Set.has(s)) {
      r.push([]);
    }

    r[r.length - 1].push(s);

    return r;
  }, [])
};

const array1 = ["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5", "str6"];
console.log(groupByArray(array1, ["str2","str5"]));
console.log(groupByArray(array1, ["str2","str3"]));
```